# How to define the image measure ("joint density") of $(X, Y)$, where $Y = h (X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, dirac-delta

I was studying the concept of sufficient statistics, and I saw a few documents (such as this one https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-381-statistical-method-in-economics-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT14_381F13_lec4.pdf) where people consider conditional probability densities of the form $f_{X|T=t}(x)$ or joint densities of the form $f_{X,T}(x,t)$, where $X$ and $T$ are real random variables and $T = T(X)$ is a function of $X$.

I was surprised reading this kind of thing, since the vector $(X, T)$ does not admit a joint density, and in this case we can't even define the conditional density $f_{X|T=t}(x)$ (can we?).

So I started to think about the following problem:

> Let $X, Y$ be two real random variables such that $Y = h(X)$. We consider that $X$ admits the density $f_X(x)$. How can we define the image measure $\mu_{X,Y}$ of the couple $(X, Y)$, such that, for $A \in \mathcal{B}({\mathbb{R}^2})$:
>
> $$
> P((X, Y) \in A) = \int_A \mu_{X,Y}(\mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y)
> $$

My first try was to define the set $C = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y = h(x)\}$, the projection $\pi_x: (x,y)\mapsto x$ and then:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
P((X, Y) \in A) = \int_{\pi_x(A\cap C)} f_X(x) \;\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

But I still couldn't write it as a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then I found the answer of spaceisdarkgreen to this question [Joint density of dependent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308859/joint-density-of-dependent-random-variables), where he defines:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}\tag{2}
 f_{X, Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)\delta(y - h(x))
\end{equation}

I understood the idea behind this definition, **but does it formally define a measure** on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Or the Dirac should be interpreted as a distribution and not a measure?
When I apply it (informally) to a set of the form $M\times N \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, I get:

$$
P((X,Y) \in M\times N) = \int_M f_X(x) \int_N \delta(y-h(x)) \; \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x = \int_{M\cap h^{-1}(N)} f_X (x) \; \mathrm{d}x
$$

which is coherent with the definition \eqref{eq:1}.

Could you help me to give a formal explanation to \eqref{eq:2}? Does it define a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**
This document http://www.elac.pvamu.edu/Include/Math/AAM/Vol3_No1/Chakraborty%20MAA-R14-071406%20Final%20_4_%206-12-08.pdf shows a lot of applications of the Dirac distribution in probability/statistics, but it does not provide any rigorous justification to its use. Does anyone know any reference that presents it in a rigorous way?

Answer (score 1):

The image measure is given by the formula
$$
\mu_{X,Y}(A)=P((X,Y)\in A)=\int_{\Bbb R} 1_A(x,h(x))f_X(x)\,dx.
$$
As $\mu_{X,Y}$ is concentrated on the graph of $h$, which is a Borel subset of $\Bbb R^2$ of Lebesgue measure $0$ (Fubini), $\mu_{X,Y}$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, so it does not admit a density. The utility of the delta function formalism in this context is not apparent.